# Using gstreamer how can I generate encrypted hls streams

Tags: encryption, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

Can anyone help me generate a GStreamer pipeline to create an encrypted hls stream? I have been able to do the following which works well but I would like to add encryption to the final output.

`gst-launch-1.0 -v souphttpsrc location=http://192.168.1.20/1.ts ! tsdemux program-number=1 name=tsmux tsmux.video_0_0044 ! queue ! muxer. tsmux.audio_0_0045 ! queue ! aacparse ! muxer. mpegtsmux name=muxer ! hlssink location="test/hlssink.%05d.ts" playlist-location="test/playlist.m3u8" max-files=6  target-duration=6`